# .htaccess - only one referral allowed; fastcgi

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, referer

I am creating `.htaccess` file first time and it doesn't work for me.

My htaccess looks as following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)?mysite.net/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

`.htaccess` file is in directory that corresponds to subdomain `support.somesite.com`
I want to allow access only for `https://www.mysite.net` domain (`https://www.mysite.net/qa/test.aspx` and other has links to `support.somesite.com`)

However, above .htacess doesn't work. I ran phpinfo and see that Server API is cgi/fastcgi and not Apache. I do not know if this is an issue.

Is this something with mod_rewrite module? Can I use above htaccess with fastcgi Server API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP_REFERER does not work with https.

Comment: So what you suggest then?I have found the followign link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390862/http-referer-lost-using-https This is almost my case. So I have two pages. One is https://www.mysite.net and https://www.mysite.net/qa, it is hosted on IIS and there are ASPNET pages. Another is support.somesite.com which is hosted on Apache server, but currently the client uses only html pages. I need support.somesite.com allow only https://www.mysite.net as referel. It is just for reduce traffic a bit, but it is not so important security issue. So what should I use?

Comment: I want to add that first site is https, second site is http, so I am linking from https to http.

Comment: That's it. When you're from an https page, the HTTP_REFERER header is not available. I don't have anything else to suggest, just follow what was suggested in that SO question. Basically, add a secret into the url (so that the url linked from mysite.net/qa changes every time) and verify it in your 2nd site, a secret is like (REMOTE_ADDR, hmac(REMOTE_ADDR)) where hmac is just like a hash function. However, IMHO traffic is cheap and in this case you should not do anything.