# Referrer stripped when coming from Google site builder page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can anyone verify what I am seeing is not a bug?  I am checking the referrer when someone comes to my site which is an ASP.NET C# store site. When I link from any of the other sites I control, my main page sees the referrer properly.

I am trying to support another third-party site that's linking to me and they have a Google site page at sites.google.com/site/whatever and when I follow that link my referrer on my main page is blank.

Is that something Google is doing or is it a truly bizarre bug in my code. (I know you can't see my code but I would like verification that Google is stripping referrer from their sites.google pages please.)

Thanks

Comment: Use a tool like [**Fiddler**](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see exactly what is being sent, and what headers are being set.  There may be some hidden redirects in there stripping away the context information.

Comment: I believe if they are coming from HTTPS, you won't get your referrer either and I know Google recently made some changes about how they serve sites when you're logged into your Google account.  Can you check that you're coming from http:// rather than a secure site?

Comment: It is indeed coming from https.  I used Fiddler (Thanks mellamokb!!) and the Referrer is missing.  I'll do some experimentation to see if all secure links strip it or if it is just Google's and post back here.

Comment: Well, bad news for me.  Justin is right, no referrer from secure pages.  I'm going to have them add a parameter to the end of the URL when they link to us to show it is them.  Thanks to both of you for helping me find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Sites is HTTPS by default, which means no referrer data is passed.  This may be part of Google's move to HTTPS across the board.  Implications discussed [here](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2012/03/upcoming-changes-in-googles-http.html).

HTTP RFC says referrers shouldn't be sent when going from HTTPS to HTTP.  Not sure if HTTPS to HTTPS will work either.  See discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390862/http-referer-lost-using-https).

Comment: I wish Justin had answered this instead of just putting the answer in a comment but he didn't.  I'll give him the props and you the points. :)  Thanks for the links.